# How to resolve domain name in express.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, nginx, routes

I have an expressJS script which is contain a mongoDB fetch. My goal is to make this API available to present my JSON based test list on a route of /api/testlist.

I can reach and see that the index page is available, but for some reason I can not see the same with the route API.

The weird thing is that the IP + port/api/testlist is reachable, but if I type my domain address instead, well I got the 404. Even I can reach the index page with the domain address.

The script:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const port = 3000; 
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

const client = new MongoClient(uri);

try {
  client.connect();
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB:', err);
}

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html"); 
});

app.get("/api/testlist", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const collection = client.db('test').collection('test');
    const result = await collection.find({}).toArray();
    
    if (result.length > 0) {
      res.json({ result });
    } else {
      res.json({ message: 'items not found'});
    }

  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error querying MongoDB:", err);
    res.status(500).send("Error querying the database");
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

I tried to configure the nginx server config. Also the mongoDB config, but no luck.

Something is fishy in the script that I can not see I guess. Or forgot to present.

Comment: Look in your browsers developer tools,  what `url` is it trying to load?.   Node doesn't have anything to do with how domains are resolved, it will only ever see an IP connection, the domain will only be part of the request Header.

Comment: What does your nginx config look like? Perhaps you are only proxying through specific paths

Comment: Good note @Keith I'm going to investigate that hint

Comment: The nginx config is like [this](https://pastebin.com/h5Xj2tFM) @Phil

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved the problem. All I had to do was create an empty file next to my server.js script and name it testlist. No formatting or anything. I also removed the /api from my server.js route. So now it is just /testlist. And with that it works to reach the API route and get the list via domain. A bit strange for me, though